# Cannot create Unwind Segue Xcode 11 Via Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, storyboard

Ever since the latest Xcode came out I Am unable to connect my view controller to its exit, to create an unwind segue. ( right-clicking the circle and dragging it to the exit door icon)

[image]

Does anyone know why this is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: right-click? Try control + drag the view controller icon to the Exit icon

Comment: @TonyMkenu this is precisely the issue, upon right-clicking and dragging to exit icon it would work in previous Xcode. However, in 11.3 I can't seem to do it anymore. Was this a change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still working... right-click or control + drag... **but**..

> ```
> Before you can begin adding unwind segues in Interface Builder, you
> must define at least one unwind action
> ```

exemple

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    let sourceViewController = sender.source
    // Pull any data from the view controller which initiated the unwind segue.
}
```